# What is the species of this strange insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I first saw this photo long time ago, and I still can't identify the species of this insect:

[image]

Comment: any idea of the geographic region it was taken?

Comment: I didn't see the date, time, and location on this photo when I first saw it. I also typed "long-proboscis fly" on Google, but there was no photos that match the species of this insect.

Comment: it's a kind of planthopper. I can't figure out which kind. And without geography, might be impossible. See: https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/877149-Thanatodictya-tillyardi/browse_photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be in the family Dictyopharidae, a long  nosed planthopper.

This analysis is not absolute as there are exceptions.

There are two features to put it in Dictyopharidae and Fulgoridae. The (tiny) antennae are below the eyes, not between them; and the head has a big protrusion.

The pattern and placement of spines on the legs, and the pattern of veins on the wings would help to identify it to genus level.

A helpful resource is http://hydrodictyon.eeb.uconn.edu/projects/cicada/simon_lab/peet_pages/07_Bartlett.pdf

Picture is of Rhynchomitra spp. from Wikipedia.
[image]

Comment: You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 